# sum of row in matlab

Tags: matlab

i have this sample matrix in matlab i can get the sum of column each separate

```
matrix=[1 2 3 4;1 2 3 4;1 2 3 4;1 2 3 4]

sum(matrix)
```

result

matrix =

```
 1     2     3     4
 1     2     3     4
 1     2     3     4
 1     2     3     4
```

ans =

```
       4     8    12    16
```

i want to have these colum as they are and get sum of each row by itself like result should be

```
rowsum=10    10   10    10
```

then add each row with column separate as a final result

```
1=14
2=18
3=22
4=26
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the sum you've already calculated and the sum of the transposed matrix to get the result you're looking for;

```
> sum(matrix)+sum(matrix')

ans =

   14   18   22   26
```

Comment: thanxs that helped alot just what ii was looking for

Answer (score 0):

More generally, to calculate the sum of each row directly just give the relevant dimension to `sum` to sum over the columns instead of rows:

```
>> sum(matrix,2)
ans =

   10
   10
   10
   10
```